# Is the famous problem number #6 solvable in first order Peano arithmetic?

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms, vieta-jumping

I just came accross the famous "very difficult" problem 6 of the 1988 International Mathematical Olympiad:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers and $k=\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}$. Show that if $k$ is an integer then $k$ is a perfect square.

The solution involves Vieta jumping or a descending sequence, for those interested the exact solution can be read [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vieta-root-jumping/).

Question: Is this kind of descending sequence proof possible under first order Peano axioms?

Comment: Yes. It is straightforward to reorganize arguments by infinite descent or similar approaches as proofs by induction, and in this specific case there is nothing in the argument that is not readily formalizable in PA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easily provable in PA. Indeed, at a glance the tiny fragment I$\Sigma_1$ is already enough.

PA, remember, gives us induction along $\mathbb{N}$ for *all formulas expressible in the language of arithmetic*. Principles like "every Goodstein sequence terminates" are proved via "long induction" (e.g. induction along $\epsilon_0$), but something basic like Vieta jumping - where the statements involved are all arithmetic, and the induction is just along $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual ordering - goes through in PA without any difficulty.